# Google custom search on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, search

The google custom search has recently stopped working on a client's website. Here's the source code

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('URLGOESHERE/');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.SMALL_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
  }, true);
</script>
```

Is this the most recent code to use? I've been looking to see if this code has been changed recently by Google but cannot see anything.

The problem is the search button just doesn't let you search, almost like it's closed off.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: CustomSearchControl('URLGOESHERE/') - on line 5 - did you already change the url?

Comment: Yes I did, that says the client's web address which I need to keep private - sorry, I understand that'd help sort the problem.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in an iframe

```
<form id="cse-search-box" action="http://google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="YOUR SEARCH ENGINE ID goes here" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<img src="http://www.google.com/cse/images/google_custom_search_smwide.gif">
```